# Why is traffic not being properly routed through iOS's Network Extension Tunnel Provider?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, networking, vpn

I am experimenting with iOS's network extension tunnel provider, which uses NETunnelProviderManager and related classes, and Apple's sample provider SimpleTunnel which works with a test server tunnel_server.

I am able to get things working so that I map my iPhone device to the address 192.168.2.2, and then I am able to hit an apache web server running locally on the tunnel_server (Running on my macbook pro) from that same IP address. I believe this proves the tunnel is working since normally I cannot access 192.168.2.2 from my iPhone (although I can access this same macbook pro from a different email address). Also, when I add logging on the client and server sides I can see the TCP/IP packets flowing for this case.

However, when I tried to access yahoo.com from the same iPhone (keeping my VPN connection on), it is not able to access. I then tested pinging an yahoo.com address from my phone (for example 98.138.253.109) and I cannot reach that when the VPN is up. So this explains why the DNS resolution is not working on the iPhone. I also cannot seem to reach any other addresses through the iPhone.

The strange thing is that for these cases that don't work, there is no packets flowing through the logging in tunnel_server or the extension provider. So the traffic is being limited now, even though I have not specified any such limitations.

If someone has any idea how to further triage this please let me know.

UPDATE:

I verified that the SimpleTunnel program is properly adding the default route so that all IP traffic from the iPhone is routed into the tunnel (this is done in PacketTunnelProvider.swift: createTunnelSettingsFromConfiguration(...)).

With this route in, I am effectively seeing all traffic on the device blocked, as if it is trying to route it but getting lost somewhere before it gets to the tunnel, because I don't see it hitting the logging in the extension (specifically in ClientTunnelConnection.swift: handlePackets()).

Since it is clearly not reaching the server side, I am pretty sure there is no issue on that end, which leaves some configuration on the client side. However, I'm not sure where to look.

UPDATE 2:

I've tried using WireShark on the machine where tunnel_server and inspecting the utun2 interface, and I can see traffic coming in when I try to hit access the server machine itself from my iPhone via 192.168.2.2, the assigned address.

However, I don't see much other TCP or ICMP traffic on this interface. For example, if I try to ping one of my DNS servers (using it's IP address) from my iPhone, I don't see any ICMP packed on the utun2 interface.

I also tried changing the assigned address from 192.168.2.2 to the address 10.15.68.200 which is on the same subnet as my server (10.15.68.160), but no luck.

This is what the resultant utun2 interface looks like on the server side:

```
utun2: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    inet 10.15.68.200 --> 10.15.68.200 net mask 0xfffff800
```

I also found [this post](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/12450) which alludes to a similar problem, but it wasn't of too much help.

UPDATE 3:

I found these entries in the iPhone's log right around the time the tunnel gets connected. I feel they may be related to the cause of why things aren't working, but not sure exactly what is going on.

```
Feb 23 09:28:06 iPhone PacketTunnel[1260] <Warning>: Tunnel connection state changed to Connecting
Feb 23 09:28:06 iPhone networkd[97] <Error>: -[NETClient sendMessage:replyHandler:] attempting to send an XPC message to a suspended client PacketTunnel.1260! This is a bug!
Feb 23 09:28:06 iPhone configd[38] <Notice>: network changed
Feb 23 09:28:06 iPhone PacketTunnel[1260] <Warning>: Tunnel connection state changed to Connected
Feb 23 09:28:06 iPhone configd[38] <Notice>: network changed: v4(utun0+:10.15.68.200, en0, pdp_ip0) DNS! Proxy!

Feb 23 09:28:06 iPhone networkd[97] <Error>: __42-[NETClientConnection     evaluateNetworkPath]_block_invoke apsd.103 connection 75: trigger network agents (<NULL>) error Error Domain=NWPathEvaluatorErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"
Feb 23 09:28:06 iPhone networkd[97] <Error>: __42-[NETClientConnection evaluateNetworkPath]_block_invoke com.apple.Safar.1236 connection 4: trigger network agents (<NULL>) error Error Domain=NWPathEvaluatorErrorDomain Code=1 "    (null)"
Feb 23 09:28:06 iPhone networkd[97] <Error>: __42-[NETClientConnection evaluateNetworkPath]_block_invoke com.apple.Safar.1236 connection 5: trigger network agents (<NULL>) error Error Domain=NWPathEvaluatorErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"
Feb 23 09:28:06 iPhone nesessionmanager[355] <Notice>: NESMVPNSession[Demo VPN:296CC30E-E2BD-4C73-8C29-E5264E9C4285]: status changed to connected
```

UPDATE 4:

Viewing the routing table using the "IT Tools" app on the iPhone shows the following: (Will only show the top part of the IPv4 routing)

```
default        link#16       utun0   UCS
default        10.15.64.1    en0     UGSci
10.15.64.0/21  link#8        en0     UCS
10.15.64.1/32  link#8        en0     UCS
...
10.15.68.200   10.15.68.200  utun0   U
...
```

The first strange thing is that there is two default gateways, which seems like it should never happen. Having said that, the first gateway is the utun0 which is what I would expect, although I am not seeing all the traffic to go the network tunnel provider extension. The last of these routes seems to be the only one what is working, since I actually can see packets going to that IP address go through the tunnel.

UPDATE 5:

I discovered that the traffic is actually going from utun2 to en0 on my server, but for some reason was not coming back to the server from outside. A look at the source IP address showed the packets were not being properly natted, since they still had source addresses of 192.168.2.2

By adding the below rule to pf.conf (for pfctl) I was able to get natting working there, such that it changed the source address to my server's address:

```
nat on en0 inet from !(en0) to any -> (en0)
```

Now I actually see return packets from my final destination coming into en0. However, I do not see these routed back to utun2. It seems like there may be another NAT rule I need to add, but after trying many different things, nothing works.

Comment: I've also implemented the PacketTunnelProvider,
And everything works well while Im on 3G, but when Im on WIFI, I also get that error: Error Domain=NWPathEvaluatorErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)

Comment: @Roee84: Thanks for that important information! Right now my server cannot be accessed externally so unfortunately I cannot test with 3G. However, can you tell me if you had to do any special routing/NAT setup? Also are you using the server_tunnel program and extension in the apple sample unchanged?

Comment: No, I'm using my own version, but as you can see, it's has its own problems. more generally, I keep getting also this error on WIFI - 
trigger network agents NWPathEvaluatorErrorDomain Code=1

Comment: This is somewhat unrelated but would be very helpful if you could answer. Are the Foundation Networking and Network Extension API's only available for use with Enterprise Developer accounts?

Comment: You do need special entitlements which have be to specifically requested from Apple. I think they will consider giving them to non-enterprise developer accounts but I am not 100%. Contact Apple and see what they say.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not absolutely sure from your post, but if you're running on a macbook and you have the VPN icon on the top of your phone, meaning the tunnel has been established, but can't access the net from the phone - it probably means you have a routing problem on your mac.

This is how I fixed it...

1. tunnel_server/config.plist

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
   <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-/  
   <plist version="1.0">  
   <dict>  
     <key>IPv4</key>  
     <dict>  
     <key>Routes</key>  
     <array>  
     <dict>  
     <key>Netmask</key>  
     <string>255.255.255.0</string>  
     <key>Address</key>  
     <string>10.10.5.0</string>  
     </dict>  
     </array>  
     <key>Pool</key>  
     <dict>  
     <key>EndAddress</key>  
     <string>10.10.5.10</string>  
     <key>StartAddress</key>  
     <string>10.10.5.3</string>  
     </dict>  
     </dict>  
   </dict>  
   </plist>
   ```
2. Configure the NAT

   ```
   sudo vi /etc/pf.conf
   ```

   add the following:

   ```
   nat-anchor "simpleTunnel"  
   load anchor "simpleTunnel" from "/etc/pf.anchors/simpleTunnel"
   ```

   While keeping in mind that the pf.conf has an order it needs to have the settings in.

   So after adding, mine looks like this: (added the rules after the scrub anchor)

   ```
   scrub-anchor "com.apple/*"
   nat-anchor "simpleTunnel"
   load anchor "simpleTunnel" from "/etc/pf.anchors/simpleTunnel"
   nat-anchor "com.apple/*"
   rdr-anchor "com.apple/*"
   dummynet-anchor "com.apple/*"
   anchor "com.apple/*"
   ```
3. Edit:

   ```
   sudo vi /etc/pf.anchors/simpleTunnel
   nat on en0 from 10.10.0.0/16 to any -> en0
   ```
4. Run the following:

   ```
   sudo sysctl net.inet.ip.forwarding=1  
   sudo sysctl net.inet.ip.fw.enable=1  
   sudo pfctl -evf /etc/pf.conf
   ```
5. Now the responses can arrive at en0

Let me know if it helps.